# Как изменить параметр image в компоненте image target behavior? (Vuforia)

Tags: unity3d, ar, vuforia

При старте скрипта создаётся image target которому должен присваевается параметр image.
Я пытался сделать это как-то так:`gameObject.GetComponent("ImageTargetBehaviour").Image = myImage;` 
myImage имеет тип texture2D

ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ПОМОГИТЕ!  СРОКИ ГОРЯТ! [image: компонент ImageTargerBehaviour]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: Мне нужно узнать Id параметра Ане способ получения компонента!

Comment: `gameObject.GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>().Image = myImage;`

Comment: Увы, но для начала придётся научиться получать компанент.

Comment: Компонент получается нормально и другие его свойства (enabled, name и т.д.) я могу изменить но не это!

Comment: Вообще-то GetComponent("Component") это один из способов получения компонента. А через GetComponent<Component>() ни один компонент vuforia не обнаруживается!

Comment: Поясняю: мне нужно знать какое название параметра написать после GetComponent("ImageTargetBehaviour"). Image, Texture, Sprite не подходят ни с заглавной ни со строчной буквы

Comment: Одевай штаны через голову и дальше...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить переменную из другого скрипта:
`gameObject.GetComponent<ImageTargetBehaviour>().Image = myImage;`

> Обратите внимание на синтаксис GetComponent: без кавычек, название компонента (в вашем случае скрипта) в треугольных кавычках, потом круглые

Чтобы задать эту картинку самому объекту с компонентом Image:
`gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = myImage;`

> Об этом вы не просили, но лучше дать больше, чем меньше.